# Why Flutter can't find the new API toImageSync for RenderRepaintBoundary class?

Tags: flutter, image, render, screen, capture

The method `'toImageSync'` was recently added to Flutter for `RenderRepaintBoundary`. As shown in this link.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImageSync.html

However, it gives me the following error when I try to use it. It works fine if I switch to 'toImage()'. I'm running the latest stable 3.3.10 version.

```
**The method 'toImageSync' isn't defined for the class 'RenderRepaintBoundary'.**

final boundary =
        key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
ui.Image image = boundary.toImageSync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the latest stable 3.3.10 version doesn't recognize `toImageSync`,  but to make it work I simpy updated my flutter to the nearest beta version.

1. Make sure your flutter path is the same as you use in android studio
2. Upgrade to beta:

```
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter -version
```

3. Set the minimum flutter version in your `pubspec.yaml` to your installed version:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
  flutter: '>=3.7.0-1.4.pre'
```